# new-object System.IO.FileStream passing the file name Vs passing the file path

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

I have this code as part of a script which get  SharePoint on-premises file and save it to local folder:-

```
$file = $spSourceWeb.GetFile($ItemAttachmentURLPrefix + $attachment)
$bytes = $file.OpenBinary() 
$AttachmentFileName = $FilePrefix + "_AP_" + $InvoiceIDFormatted + "_" + $attachment
$Attachmentpath = $AttachmentFolder + $AttachmentFileName
$fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($Attachmentpath, "OpenOrCreate") 
$fs.Write($bytes, 0 , $bytes.Length)    
$fs.Close()
```

now at first i thought the `$Attachmentpath` inside the `$fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($Attachmentpath, "OpenOrCreate")` will define the path where the file will be saved locally, but seems this variable `$Attachmentpath` will define the file name.. so what define the file local path?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in the `FileStream(String, FileMode)` constructor is a file path, not a file name.

To avoid guessing, you can check the list of all overloads in [the Microsoft' .NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=net-7.0)